# Got problems with the root-size in HTML/CSS. Could somebody give me hint?

Tags: html, css

I currently doing the "HTML and CSS Fundamentals"-Course from W3C at edX.org and have some problems with on task (see below) which I got:

--> With the HTML below, please size the text using different units:

Use px units to set the root size of the text for the document.

Use rem units to size the h1 and li tags.

Change the text size of the root CSS rule. You should observe all the text of the document adjusting appropriately.

Change the h1 so that it uses px units. As the root CSS rule is changed, the h1 will no longer adjust with the rest of the document. <--

I´ve written the following code for the -section (as the course suggested), but it does not work. Just the

-elements are changing their size. My simple question is:  Why?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Greetz

I´ve tried various typing variants and I´ve also changed the localization of the style-element (in the head- und the html-section). Nothing worked yet.

```css
body {font-size: 20px}   /* h1 and h2 do not chang this, li does...   why is that?*/
h1 {font-size: 3rem}
h2 {font-size: 2rem}
li {font-size: 1rem}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Learning Life</title>
  </head>
 
<body>
<header>
  <h1> This headline doesn´t change size </h1>
  <h2> This one either..</h2>
</header>

<ul>
  <li> The list elements work </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Isn't the "root CSS rule" `:root` ?

Comment: `h1` and other `hX` won't change since the rule that changes their font size are more  specific (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Ok..      got it. I used "head, body" first and the above "body" as second try. The solution ist "html, body".